# Visual studio stopped working while build my solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm using VS2008 and I used more than 10 Jquery plugins in my master form and its working Perfectly but when I build my solution Its take too long time to build and its stopped working.Before I add those plugins i got no issue on Visual Studio .How do i solve this .

```
<link href="../AdminCss/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../AdminCss/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../AdminCss/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- addons -->

    <script src="../js/chart-plugins.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/jquery.uniform.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <!-- plugins loader -->

    <script src="../js/loader.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script src="../js/customCalender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <link href="../AdminCss/Admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: remove the plugins? If you want a better answer, you'll need to be a lot more specific, and at least list the error you get when visual studio crashes, and perhaps list the plugins that you suspect to be causing the issue.

Comment: I updated my question with some Plugins which i used.I need those plugins. @Claies

Comment: it looks like you listed a series of javascript and css files.  As these are not compiled, I fail to see how any of these would have anything to do with Visual Studio crashes.

Comment: I removed the Plugins which are referenced from online server,then i downloaded those plugins and referenced in my local . @Claies thanks